# How would I bind the value from input form to a component in jsx? The function is inside the appjs and i need to figure out how to set state to jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im very much new to react and are just starting out here, I'd like to have someone explain how to set the state of the input from the createEmployee function to the Employee JSX. Id very much appreciate being shown how to do this and an explanation on why and how to set this up. I have some exmployees already declared and would like to add more upon the submission of the createEmployee form. I know I could also create a new form component but my current problem is working with just vanilla js. Theres some other jsx files in there such as kounter i had included from the tutorial im using as well.

Im' very much green thumb still so go easy please :(

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './Employee';
import './Cou3';
import Employee from './Employee';
import Counter3 from './Cou3';
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
//import Counter from './Counter';
import Kounter from './Kounter2';

const empInfo = [
    
  {
      firstName: "Jack",
      lastName:"Smith",
      age:"21",
  },

  {
      firstName: "steph",
      lastName:"garcia",
      age:"21",
  },

  {
      firstName: "joe",
      lastName:"nieto",
      age:"21",
  },

  {
      firstName: "Jack",
      lastName:"josh",
      age:"21",
  },
]


 
    function App() {
          
        
          function createEmployee(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            const employee = {
              firstName: e.target.children.name.value,
              lastName: e.target.children.lname.value,
              age: e.target.children.age.value,
            }
            // Take employee and push it to the employee array
            // Update employee array to use setState
            console.log(employee)
          }
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <h1>Company Directory</h1>
                <form onSubmit={(event)=>createEmployee(event)}>
                  <input name="name"/>
                  <input name="lname"/>
                  <input name="age"/>
                  <button type="submit">submit</button>
                </form>
                {empInfo.map(employee =>{
                  const {firstName, lastName, age} = employee;
                  return(
                    <Employee firstName={firstName} lastName = {lastName} age = {age}/>
                  );
        
                })}
        
                  <Kounter/>        
                
                
                {/*
                <Employee firstName="Jack" lastName="Smith"/>
                <Employee firstName="Steph" lastName="garcia"/>
                <Employee firstName="Joe" lastName="nieto"/>
                <Employee firstName="Jack" lastName="josh"/>
                <Counter3/>
                */}
              </header>
        
            </div>
          );
        }
        
        
        export default App;
```

/////EMPLOYE JSX

```
import React from "react";
 


const Employee = (props) =>{
console.log(props);
const {firstName, lastName, age} = props;
return (
<div>
<h1>Employee name: {firstName} {lastName} {age}</h1>
</div>
);

};



export default Employee;
```

Comment: Something of this kind maybe https://jsfiddle.net/v2osjgyL/4/ ?

Comment: OO very good it is working, however i guess i failed to specify for it to add multiple employees instead of just one, could you explain the use of                                                                 
  const [state, setState]= React.useState([empInfo])
  React.useEffect(()=>{})t and why they were important for this?

Comment: Ops, `React.useEffect(()=>{})` is not doing anything, ignore it :) `const [state, setState]=React.useState([...empInfo])` copies the initial data into the component state, this way each time state changes the component is re-rendered, so you get your new employees on the screen. What do you mean by adding multiple employees though? where will the multiple entries be coming from?

Comment: Okay cool ty for explaining that and in your example, it creates a new employee,i assume its simply print it via the    <input value={firstName+' '+lastName} />, when im calling it im calling it as {state.map(employee => {
          const {firstName, lastName, age, } = employee;
          return(
            <Employee firstName={firstName} lastName = {lastName} age = {age}/>
          );
however when i call it, it enters just one value for the employee instead of making a new one like yours.

Comment: If you just replace `input` with `Employee` ti shouldn't make any difference, that is it should print them all. I'm not sure what is inside `Employee` though, and how they're styled. Can they be rendered one on top of the other? Can you add `Employee` code to your post?

Comment: I've attached the Employee component, thank you for the help :D

Comment: looks like it's working okay, no? https://jsfiddle.net/v2osjgyL/5/

Comment: so it works, however it's creating a single instance of the newly added employee, but, when i enter in new credentials it writes over the previous one that was created. i'm curious as how to edit the code for it to create a new instance everytime and add to the list.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following, each time I press submit it adds a new employee to the end of the list and keeps all the previous ones in place.

Comment: hmm im running live server through vs code, would that maybe be the issue there?

Comment: I don't think vs code can be causing this issue. Are you sure you have the same logic as in the fiddle? You may be getting this behaviour if you for example have `setState(state => [...empInfo, employee])` instead of `setState(state => [...state, employee])`